# Redux - Combining multiple reducers result in state clearing

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

Fairly new to redux, and have gone through the official guides. Now I'm trying to do something solo. I have two reducers and am using react-thunk. When I dispatch an action after the first one it clears my collection of my other reducer. To illustrate what I mean is I have:

**Actions.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';

function fetchAtms() {
  return axios.get('http://localhost:4567');
}

export const recievedAtms = (atms) => {
  return {
    type: 'RECIEVED_ATMS',
    atms
  }
}

export const completed = () => {
  return {
    type: 'COMPLETED',
  }
}

export const loadMore = () => {
  return {
    type: 'LOAD_MORE',
  }
}

export const loadAtms = (forPerson) => {
  return function (dispatch) {
    return fetchAtms().then((response) => {
      let atms = response.data.map((item) => {return item['location']})
      dispatch(recievedAtms(atms));
      // When dispatch(completed()); is called
      // it is clears my app collection.
      dispatch(completed());
      // $r.store.getState() => Object {app: {atms: []}, isLoading: false, router: Object}
    }, (error) => {
        console.log('implement me');
    })
  }
}
```

**Reducers**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux';

const app = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'RECIEVED_ATMS':
      return {
        atms: action.atms
      }
    default:
      return {};
  }
}

const isLoading = (state = true, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'COMPLETED':
      return !state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const appReducer = combineReducers({
  app,
  isLoading,
  router: routerReducer
});

export default appReducer;
```

**Store.js**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { routerMiddleware} from 'react-router-redux';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import appReducer from './reducers/app';

export const history = createHistory()

const middleware = routerMiddleware(history);

const store = createStore(appReducer, applyMiddleware(middleware, thunk));

export default store;
```

If you hone in on `Actions.js` where in the `loadAtms` function I:

1. Fetch my atms
2. Dispatch receivedAtms
3. Dispatch Completed

When I dispatch `completed()` it clear my atms collection. I'm not entirely sure. I would not expect that since the states between the two reducers are separate. My expectation is:

After I've fired `completed()` I do not expect it to clear my collection of atms. The resulting state after calling `completed()` should look like this:

```
{
  isLoading: false,
  app: {atms: [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}]}
}
```

currently what is happening is this:

```
{isLoading: false, app: {}}
```

Any thoughts on what I may have done wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your atms reducer is returning `{}` if the action isn't one it is looking for. Instead, you should be returning `state` I believe. So:

```
const app = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'RECIEVED_ATMS':
      return {
        atms: action.atms
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```